# In akka does a child process run in the same process as its parent actor?

Tags: akka.net

In akka does a child process always run in the same process as its parent actor?

Is there documentation?

Comment: Does `process` mean something special in the context of `.net`? If not you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all actors are created within the same process (and AppDomain) as their parent. There are few situations where this is not the case:

- Remote deployment
- Cluster pool routers

In both of those, all parameters send to an actor constructor will be serialized and passed to another machine, which will work as a physical host for an actor instance.